# NSFileManager's method createDirectoryAtPath returns false result on iOS

Tags: ios, directory, nsfilemanager, create-directory

When I try to create a folder using the code bellow it returns NO with an error when I try to create a folder that already exists instead of returning YES:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp"] withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
```

Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW5) says:

```
Return Value
YES if the directory was created or already exists or NO if an error occurred.
```

So I should get YES on success or if folder exists. But I get this message when folder exists:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 516.)" UserInfo=0x200ef5f0 {NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/DA657A0E-785D-49B4-9258-DF9EBAC5D52A/Documents/temp, NSUnderlyingError=0x200ef590 "The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists"}
```

Is this a bug and should be reported to Apple or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @trojanfoe: Am I sure. I've reinstalled app. For the first time "temp" folder is created but all subsequent attempts gives me the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[NSFileManager createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:]` will fail if the file exists and it is not a directory.

So the way forward is to not bother creating the directory if it already exists and to throw an exception if it exists and is not a directory:

```
NSString *filename = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp"];
NSFileManager *fileman = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL isDir = NO;
if (![fileman fileExistsAtPath:filename isDirectory:&isDir])
{
    // Create the directory
}
else if (!isDir)
{
    NSLog(@"Cannot proceed!");
    // Throw exception
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly than either Apple's documentation or implementation is wrong?

Comment: @BorutTomazin Yeah I guess so; sounds like a bug, so you need to work around it (I think it's better to avoid doing something that doesn't need doing wherever possible anyway).

Comment: Ok. Good to know. I'll report bug to Apple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use withIntermediateDirectories YES to get the behaviour in Apple's docs.